# How to sort data from Database with DESC in Android

Tags: android, android-database

I want load data from `SQLiteDatabase` and I should sort this data with **DESC**! 
**I write below code:**

```
/*Retrieve data from database*/
public List<FavModel> getFavList() {

    // 1. initialize modelList
    List<FavModel> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
    // 2. select
    String QUERY_SELECT = "SELECT * FROM " + FavContract.favInfo.TABLE_NAME;
    // 3. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // 4. read from query
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY_SELECT, null);
    // 5. set model data into modelList
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            FavModel model = new FavModel();
            model.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            model.setImage(cursor.getString(2));
            model.setContent(cursor.getString(3));
            model.setDate(cursor.getString(4));
            model.setAuthor(cursor.getString(5));
            model.setCategory(cursor.getString(6));

            modelList.add(model);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    // 6. return modelList
    return modelList;
}
```

In my code, when added new item show me below of age items, but I want when added new item show me top ago items.
My mean is when added new items sort by **DESC**, not sort **ASC**.

How can I it?

Comment: You can use a convenient query methos and use a orderby param as DESC or ASC https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: @Raghunandan, Thanks, can you send me code with my above codes? please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have a specific column like id then do like

```
String QUERY_SELECT = "SELECT * FROM " + FavContract.favInfo.TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + column_name + " DESC" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

`"String QUERY_SELECT = SELECT * FROM " + FavContract.favInfo.TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + col_name + " ASC";`

Answer (score 0):

Use this query statement

```
database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table name +
                         " ORDER BY " + date column name + " DESC"
                         , new String[] {});
```